# Python Selenium Index nested Elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have 5

```
<ul class="rental-facilities">
```

and multiple `<li class="feature">` within each `<ul class="rental-facilities">`

I would like to index the 3rd rental-facilities class and 1st feature.text class

Ideally 1 line code.

Tried this but doesn't work:

```
rental = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='rental-facilities']")[3]
feature = rental.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='feature']")[1].text
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
feature = rental.find_elements_by_xpath(".//li[@class='feature']")[1].text
```

When xpathing you need a . when referencing from another element instead of driver.

Answer (score 0):

browser.find_elements_by_xpath() will return a list.  lists are 0-based index, so these should work:

```
rental = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='rental-facilities']")[2]
feature = rental.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='feature']")[0].text
```

Comment: I tried that too,but doesnt work.